# Top 5 with most friends

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Hi I'm new to SQL and I'm trying to figure out how I'm going to get the top 5 "bands" with most friends (userId) and this is what i have; a usertbl with userId as PK then a bandsTbl with bandId as PK then I have a table bandfriends with FK userId and bandId.

```
bandfriends
userid | bandId
---------------
 1     | 1
 1     | 2
 1     | 3
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read up on COUNT and GROUP BY at mysql.org

You'll want something like this (I haven't tested it):

```
SELECT bandId, COUNT(*) as fans FROM bandfriends
ORDER BY fans DESC
GROUP BY bandId
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support LIMIT. This answer looks right for MySQL.

Comment: I'm not familiar with SQL Server.  Jamie is right.  This answer is in MySQL syntax.  You might need to tweak it.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT TOP 5 bandId, fanCount
FROM 
    (SELECT bandId, COUNT(*) as fanCount
     FROM bandfriends
     GROUP BY bandId
     ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC)
```

You can also optionally specify WITH TIES in the select statement. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) and [this](http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/18477).

Comment: +1 for enlightening me to "with ties". I'm ashamed I didn't know that already.

Comment: I think you can't use an order by in a sub-select. It goes againt the relational model. You should move it to the outer select.

Comment: @neves: I don't understand your comment. The list has to be ordered before you can select the top 5 the ordering must be done in a subquery because it requires an aggregate. Also, it's not possible to break the relational model with a select. Fight it, yes, but not break it. :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
select top 5 b.b_name, count(friends) as numOfFriends 
from bands b inner join link l on b.b_id = l.bands inner join
friends f on f.f_id = l.friends 
group by b.b_name 
order by numOfFriends desc
```

If you have friends table, bands table and a link table, works for me :)