# SQL Server features/commands that most developers are unaware of

Tags: sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hidden Features of SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121243/hidden-features-of-sql-server)

I've worked as a .NET developer for a while now, but predominantly against a SQL Server database for a little over 3 years now. I feel that I have a fairly decent grasp of SQL Server from a development standpoint, but I ashamed to admit that I just learned today about "WITH TIES" from this answer - [Top 5 with most friends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236394/top-5-with-most-friends/1236414#1236414).

It is humbling to see questions and answers like this on SO because it helps me realize that I really don't know as much as I think I do and helps re-energize my will to learn more, so I figured what better way than to ask the masses of experts for input on other handy commands/features.

What is the most useful feature/command that the average developer is probably unaware of?

BTW - if you are like I was and don't know what "WITH TIES" is for, here is a good explanation. You'll see quickly why I was ashamed I was unaware of it. I could see where it could be useful though. - http://harriyott.com/2007/06/with-ties-sql-server-tip.aspx

I realize that this is a subjective question so please allow for at least a few answers before you close it. :) I'll try to edit my question to keep up a list with your response. Thanks

[EDIT] - Here is a summary of the responses Please scroll down for more information. Thanks again guys/gals.

- MERGE - A single command to INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE into a table from a row source.
- FILESTREAM feature of SQL Server 2008 allows storage of and efficient access to BLOB data using a combination of SQL Server 2008 and the NTFS file system
- CAST - get a date without a time portion
- Group By - I gotta say you should definitely know this already
- SQL Server Management Studio
- Transactions
- The sharing of local scope temp tables between nested procedure calls
- INSERT INTO
- MSDN
- JOINS
- PIVOT and UNPIVOT
- WITH(FORCESEEK) - forces the query optimizer to use only an index seek operation as the access path to the data in the table.
- FOR XML
- COALESCE
- How to shrink the database and log files
- Information_Schema
- SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS in Management Studio 2005
- Derived tables and common table expressions (CTEs)
- OUTPUT clause - allows access to the "virtual" tables called inserted and deleted (like in triggers)
- CTRL + 0 to insert null
- Spacial Data in SQL Server 2008

Comment: This ought to be a "Hidden Features" question.

Comment: @Dusty: Same for me, didn't know about WITH TIES either until now. Thank you!

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121243/hidden-features-of-sql-server).

Comment: Never mind, it already is.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121243/hidden-features-of-sql-server

Comment: I don't think this is the same, because I was not looking for hidden features. I'm looking for features that the average developer doesn't know about that they should. Some of the answers on the other question look to be at a higher level than what I am asking.

Comment: Enough with the continuous editing. I think one edit at the end of the day to summarize the responses is good enough.

Comment: Fair enough. Didn't realize that editing my own post caused headaches, but lesson learned.

Comment: Also, This is on community wiki so I don't see why it needs to be closed. Judging from the upvotes and the favorites I think that the majority was consider it a decent question. I think it would be a shame if it were deleted because it is closed.

Answer (score 11):

[FileStream in SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949109.aspx): FILESTREAM feature of SQL Server 2008 allows storage of and efficient access to BLOB data using a combination of SQL Server 2008 and the NTFS file system.

**Creating a Table for Storing FILESTREAM Data**

Once the database has a FILESTREAM filegroup, tables can be created that contain FILESTREAM columns. As mentioned earlier, a FILESTREAM column is defined as a varbinary (max) column that has the FILESTREAM attribute. The following code creates a table with a single FILESTREAM column

```
USE Production;
GO
CREATE TABLE DocumentStore (
       DocumentID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
       Document VARBINARY (MAX) FILESTREAM NULL,
       DocGUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL ROWGUIDCOL
              UNIQUE DEFAULT NEWID ())
FILESTREAM_ON FileStreamGroup1;
GO
```

Comment: +1 This is another thing I should definitely know more about.

Answer (score 9):

- In `SQL Server 2008` (and in `Oracle 10g`): [`MERGE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx).

  A single command to `INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE` into a table from a row source.
- To generate a list of numbers from `1` to `31` (say, for a calendary):

  ```
  WITH   cal AS
          (
          SELECT  1 AS day
          UNION ALL
          SELECT  day + 1
          FROM    cal
          WHERE   day <= 30
          )
  ```
- A single-column index with `DESC` clause in a clustered table can be used for sorting on `column DESC, cluster_key ASC`:

  ```
  CREATE INDEX ix_column_desc ON mytable (column DESC)

  SELECT  TOP 10 *
  FROM    mytable
  ORDER BY
          column DESC, pk
  -- Uses the index

  SELECT  TOP 10 *
  FROM    mytable
  ORDER BY
          column, pk
  -- Doesn't use the index
  ```
- `CROSS APPLY` and `OUTER APPLY`: enables to join rowsources which depend on the values of the tables being joined:

  ```
  SELECT  *
  FROM    mytable
  CROSS APPLY
          my_tvf(mytable.column1) tvf

  SELECT  *
  FROM    mytable
  CROSS APPLY
          (
          SELECT  TOP 5 *
          FROM    othertable
          WHERE   othertable.column2 = mytable.column1
          ) q
  ```
- `EXCEPT` and `INTERSECT` operators: allow selecting conditions that include `NULL`s

  ```
  DECLARE @var1 INT
  DECLARE @var2 INT
  DECLARE @var3 INT

  SET @var1 = 1
  SET @var2 = NULL
  SET @var2 = NULL

  SELECT  col1, col2, col3
  FROM    mytable
  INTERSECT 
  SELECT  @val1, @val2, @val3

  -- selects rows with `col1 = 1`, `col2 IS NULL` and `col3 IS NULL`

  SELECT  col1, col2, col3
  FROM    mytable
  EXCEPT 
  SELECT  @val1, @val2, @val3

  -- selects all other rows
  ```
- `WITH ROLLUP` clause: selects a grand total for all grouped rows

  ```
  SELECT  month, SUM(sale)
  FROM    mytable
  GROUP BY 
          month WITH ROLLUP

  Month   SUM(sale)
    ---        ---
    Jan        10,000
    Feb        20,000
    Mar        30,000
   NULL        60,000  -- a total due to `WITH ROLLUP`
  ```

Comment: +1 Here's another I was unaware. Looks like I have some more research to do. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

There are a handful of ways to get a date without a time portion; here's one that is quite performant:

```
SELECT CAST(FLOOR(CAST(getdate() AS FLOAT))AS DATETIME)
```

Indeed for SQL Server 2008:

```
SELECT CAST(getdate() AS DATE) AS TodaysDate
```

Comment: I use that method but I've always wondered if `cast(cast(getdate() as int) as datetime)` is equivalent?

Comment: +1 I found out a while back on SO that the way I was doing this was wrong because the answer I would have put got voted down. :)

Comment: SQL2008 now has a `DATE` column type. You can simply CAST(column AS DATE)

Comment: Thanks @Matthew. How would you do this for your apps on 7/2000/2005?

Answer (score 6):

It's amazing how many people work unprotected with SQL Server as they don't know about transactions!

```
BEGIN TRAN
...
COMMIT / ROLLBACK
```

Comment: +1 this is true, and yet I still don't use it.

Comment: +1 I'd say this is a must know if you don't know about this already. I use Begin Transaction and I always put rollback before the commit incase I forget and run the entire script.

Answer (score 6):

After creating a #TempTable in a procedure, it is available in all stored procedures that are then called from from the original procedure.  It is a nice way to share set data between procedures. see: http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html

Comment: +1 This reminds me of one so I'll add an answer myself. :)

Comment: Nevermind, kinda sleezy to post an answer to my own question. I was going to say INTO. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933206(SQL.80).aspx

Comment: Posting an awswer to your own question is perfectly acceptable on StackOverflow.

Comment: A necessary evil sometimes, but I like to avoid using this. It couples the stored procedures too tightly.

Comment: why the discussion of posting an awswer to your own question in my answer???

Comment: @KM, I posted an answer to my question based on your answer, but I deleted it. Sorry for the vague comment I left previously.

Answer (score 6):

COALESCE() , it accepts fields and a value to use incase the fields are null.
For example if you have a table with city, State, Zipcode you can use COALESCE() to return the addresses as single strings, IE:

City  |  State  | Zipcode

Houston   |  Texas  | 77058

Beaumont  | Texas   |  NULL

NULL      | Ohio    | NULL

if you were to run this query against the table:

```
select city + ‘  ‘ + COALESCE(State,’’)+ ‘  ‘+COALESCE(Zipcode, ‘’)
```

Would return:

Houston Texas 77058

Beaumont Texas

Ohio

You can also use it to pivot data, IE:

```
DECLARE @addresses VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @addresses = select city + ‘  ‘ + COALESCE(State,’’)+ ‘  ‘
+COALESCE(Zipcode, ‘’)             + ‘,’ FROM tb_addresses
SELECT @addresses
```

Would return:
Houston Texas 77058, Beaumont Texas, Ohio

Comment: +1 I have been waiting for someone to put that. Too much longer and I'd have added it myself. :)

Comment: Coalesce accepts n parameters, and returns the first non null value. i.e. COALESCE(field1,field2,field3,'literaldata')

Answer (score 6):

A lot of SQL Server developers still don't seem to know about the **[OUTPUT clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)** (SQL Server 2005 and newer) on the DELETE, INSERT and UPDATE statement.

It can be extremely useful to know which rows have been INSERTed, UPDATEd, or DELETEd, and the OUTPUT clause allows to do this very easily - it allows access to the "virtual" tables called `inserted` and `deleted` (like in triggers):

```
DELETE FROM (table)
OUTPUT deleted.ID, deleted.Description
WHERE (condition)
```

If you're inserting values into a table which has an INT IDENTITY primary key field, with the OUTPUT clause, you can get the inserted new ID right away:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(Field1, Field2)
OUTPUT inserted.ID
VALUES (Value1, Value2)
```

And if you're updating, it can be extremely useful to know what changed - in this case, `inserted` represents the new values (after the UPDATE), while `deleted` refers to the old values before the UPDATE:

```
UPDATE (table)
SET field1 = value1, field2 = value2
OUTPUT inserted.ID, deleted.field1, inserted.field1
WHERE (condition)
```

If a lot of info will be returned, the output of OUTPUT can also be redirected to a temporary table or a table variable (`OUTPUT INTO @myInfoTable`).

Extremely useful - and very little known!

Marc

Comment: +1 I haven't tried this yet, but if this works this will be super handy. Thanks. :)

Comment: SQL 2k5 and up, but good stuff

Comment: This rocks! Returning the row ID from an insert seems much cleaner than @@IDENTITY.

Answer (score 4):

The ["Information_Schema"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx) gives me a lot of views that I can use to gather information about the SQL objects tables, procedures, views, etc.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Management Studio 2005 you can have it automatically execute your query as a transaction. In a new query window go to Query->Query Options. Then click on the ANSI "tab" (on the left). Check SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS. Click OK. Now if you run any query in this current query window it will run as a transaction and you must manually ROLLBACK or COMMIT it before continuing. Additionally, this only works for the current query window; pre-existing/new query windows will need to have the option set.

I've personally found it useful. However, it's not for the faint of heart. You **must** remember to ROLLBACK or COMMIT your query. It will **NOT** tell you that you have a pending transaction if you switch to a different query window (or even a new one). However, it will tell you if you try to close the query window.

Comment: It would be handier if SQL Server Management Studio had toolbar buttons for commit and rollback. This is the ONLY thing I like about developing Oracle queries in TOAD.

Answer (score 3):

[PIVOT and UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx)

Comment: +1 I was waiting for someone to put this. I recently learned about this and can see how it is going to be very useful.

Answer (score 3):

[FOR XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345110(SQL.90).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

```
BACKUP LOG <DB_NAME> WITH TRUNCATE_ONLY

DBCC_SHRINKDATABASE(<DB_LOG_NAME>, <DESIRED_SIZE>)
```

When I started to manage very large databases on MS SQL Server and the log file had over 300 GB this statements saved my life. In most cases the shrink database will have no effect.

Before running them be sure to make full backup of LOG, and after running them to do a full backup of DB (restore sequence is no longer valid).

Answer (score 3):

Most SQL Server developers should know about and use derived tables and common table expressions (CTEs).

Comment: +1 I don't use either of these as much as I probably should.

Answer (score 2):

The **documentation**.

Sad to say, but I have come to the conclusion that the most hidden feature that developers are unaware of is the documentation on MSDN. Take for instance a Transact-SQL verb like RESTORE. The BOL will cover not only the [syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx) and [arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178615.aspx) of RESTORE. But this is only the tip of the iceberg when it comes to documentation. The BOL covers:

- the in depth fundamentals of recovery: [Understanding How Restore and Recovery of Backups Work in SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191455.aspx).
- end-to-end scenarios on how to deploy a recovery strategy: [Implementing Restore Scenarios for SQL Server Databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175199.aspx).
- the issues around system databases: [Considerations for Backing Up and Restoring System Databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190190.aspx).
- optimizing the recovery procedures: [Optimizing Backup and Restore Performance in SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190954.aspx).
- understanding *how to* to a restore. [Backing Up and Restoring How-to Topics (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337534.aspx).
- more corner cases and uncommon scenarios, there are examples like [Example: Piecemeal Restore of Only Some Filegroups (Full Recovery Model)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190394.aspx).

The list goes on and on, and this is just one single topic (backup and restore). Every feature of SQL Server gets similar coverage. Reckon not everything will get the detail backup and recovery gets, but everything is documented and there are How To topics for every feature.

The amount of information available is just ludicrous. Yet the documentation is one of the most underused resources, hence my vote for it being a **hidden** feature.

Comment: The amount of information they don't have on MSDN is also ludicrous.  Just select an object with a lot of members, and look at all the dimmed out names, members with no documentation.  The search engine is also the worst.  I use MSDN all the time but sure wish MS would get their act together.

Comment: @Lance Roberts: I second that opinion. I find that Google takes me quicker to the appropriate page on MSDN than searching on MSDN.

Comment: +1  @Remus: absolutely agreed... It's a feature that has so much potential. MSDN's implementation needs a lot of improvement as of today. I rarely use MSDN because I know it's going to be a chore just to wade through all of the things I'm not looking for. Please MSDN, get better with your search. Move to a new paradigm.

Comment: @Lance: can you give an example? I don't think SQL Server has objects and members, my response is about the SQL documentation not about MSDN in general.

Comment: @Raj: I search MSDN with google `-site:msdn.micrsoft.com -social` too. Even more an argument for the doccumentation being a *hidden* feature...

Answer (score 2):

How about materialised views? Add a clustered index to a view and you effectively create a table containing duplicate data that is automatically updated. Slows down inserts and updates because you are doing the operation twice but you make selecting a specific subset faster. And apparently the database optimiser uses it without you having to call it explicitly.

[Is a view faster than a simple query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439056/is-a-view-faster-than-a-simple-query)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds silly to say but I've looked a lot of queries where I just asked myself does the person just not know what GROUP BY is? I'm not sure if most developers are unaware of it but it comes up enough that I wonder sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

use ctrl-0 to insert a null value in a cell

Comment: This isn't strictly SQL Server based, but developers should know this.

Answer (score 1):

Why am I tempted to say JOINS?

Derived tables are one of my favorites. They perform so much better than correlated subqueries but may people continue to use correlated subqueries instead.

Example of a derived table:

```
select f.FailureFieldName, f.RejectedValue, f.RejectionDate,
         ft.FailureDescription, f.DataTableLocation, f.RecordIdentifierFieldName,
         f.RecordIdentifier , fs.StatusDescription 
    from dataFailures f
    join(select max (dataFlowinstanceid) as dataFlowinstanceid 
            from dataFailures 
            where dataflowid = 13)a 
    on f.dataFlowinstanceid = a.dataFlowinstanceid
    join FailureType ft on f.FailureTypeID = ft.FailureTypeID
    join FailureStatus fs on f.FailureStatusID = fs.FailureStatusID
```

Answer (score 1):

[WITH (FORCESEEK)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510478.aspx)  which forces the query optimizer to use only an index seek operation as the access path to the data in the table.

Answer (score 1):

[Spacial Data in SQL Server 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/spatial-data.aspx) i.e. storing Lat/Long data in a geography datatype and being able to calculate/query using the functions that go along with it.

It supports both Planar and Geodetic data.

Comment: +1 I haven't worked on anything that requires this, but I bet this makes it easier for people who use it.

Answer (score 1):

When I first started working as  programmer, I started with using SQL Server 2000. I had been taught DB theory on Oracle and MySQL so I didn't know much about SQL Server 2000.

But, as it turned out nor did the development staff I joined because they didn't know that you could convert `datetime` (and related) data types to formatted strings with built in functions. They were using a very inefficient custom function they had developed. I was more than happy to show them the errors of their ways... (I'm not with that company anymore... :-D)

With that annotate:

So I wanted to add this to the list:

```
 select Convert(varchar, getdate(), 101) -- 08/06/2009
 select Convert(varchar, getdate(), 110) -- 08-06-2009
```

These are the two I use most often. There are a bunch more: [CAST and CONVERT on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28SQL.80%29.aspx)

Comment: yea, I've seen people build a string with month,day,year functions and all the casting to varchars. what a mess!